# UnsatisfiedLinkError when using flink-s3-fs-hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I have experience `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when I tried to use 
`flink-s3-fs-hadoop` to sink to `s3` in my local Windows machine.

I googled and tried several solutions like download `hadoop.dll` and 
`winutils.exe`, set up `HADOOP_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables, copy `hadoop.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32`, but none of them worked.

I also tried to load the `hadoop` library myself in the code by using 
`System.loadlibrary("hadoop")`, it succeed, but the error still happen, 
anything additional step I am missing?

Here is my code (the 2nd and 3rd line is just trying to debug and it will succeed on the 2nd line but throw the `UnSatisfiedLink` exception in 3rd line):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    System.loadLibrary("hadoop"); 
    NativeIO.Windows.access(null, NativeIO.Windows.AccessRight.ACCESS_READ); 
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(); 
    env.setParallelism(1); 
    DataStream<String> ds = env.readTextFile("s3://fts-test/test/input.csv"); 
    ds.print(); 
    ds.writeAsText("s3://fts-test/test/output.csv"); 
    env.execute(); 
}
```

By the way I am using `Window 7 64 bit`, `flink 1.5`.